# Android volley StringRequest POST method failed to pass params

Tags: android, codeigniter, android-volley

I am currently trying to access my database using CodeIgniter. But I am not able to pass parameters from my StringRequest method. It said:

> Message:  Undefined index: email

Here is my php code:

```
public function index() {
    echo $_POST['email'];
}
```

Here is my StringRequest:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SEND_REQUEST_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d("Volley Error", error.getMessage());
    }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", "test@test.com");
            return params;
        }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

I have also tried to add:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return params;
}
```

Notes:

1. I know there is 'bug' in passing parameters using jsonrequest so I use stringrequest instead.
2. I have override the getBodyContentType method.
3. It doesn't need authorization.
4. It works fine when I test it with Postman.

Another thing to be noted:
It works if I hit the url to a single plain php file to echo the POST value. But it just can't get into the php files in my codeIgniter.

UPDATES:
I found out that although i used POST method from my android apps, somehow codeigniter takes it as a GET method. I know this using

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

Answer (score 1):

```
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", "test@test.com");
                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
```

I hope this post can help you

Comment: thank you for your help, but my current code have actually use this pattern because AppController is a class I create that manage the volley requestqueue